# When form target a html and action another html in IE11, it opens two pages at last

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

**This problem is happened only in Windows2012R2.In Windows8.1 ,it's OK.**

---

This is my first time to ask question at stackoverflow. If I do something rude here, please forgive me.:）

There are three html files.a.html,b.html and test.html.
In test.html,there is a from which has a submit button.IF you click the button,it will first execute a js function named "goOpeEvtURL".In this function, it will open a window (a.html).
The form of test.html,has an attribute name action which's value is "b.html" and also has an attribute named "trget" which's value is "a.html".

If we open the test.html and click the [Click] button, it  will popup only one  new window which shows "Result of b!!"

I tryed in IE10 and firefox,the result is "Result of b!!"
But, when I run this test.html in IE11 and click the [Click] button,it popups two windows!
one showed "Result of a!!" and another showed "Result of b!!"

I wish it will just popup  one window("Result of b!!" showed) in IE11.
How can I do lick that? T_T

---

a.html → form's target value

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE7">
<TITLE>a.html</TITLE>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="body_base">
<STRONG>Result of a!!</STRONG><BR>
<HTML>
```

---

b.html → form's action value

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE7">
<TITLE>b.html</TITLE>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="body_base">
<STRONG>Result of b!!</STRONG><BR>
```

test.html → the html which has form in it.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE7">
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
function goOpeEvtURL(kind)
{

    SubmitFlag = true;
    OTHERWIN = window.open("a.html", "aaaaa","width=" + 300 + ",height="
        + 400 +         "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,,resizable=yes,,top=200,left=200");
    return;
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="body_base">
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="b.html" 
NAME="NODESECLET"  onReset='return false;' onSubmit="return SubmitFlag;" TARGET="aaaaa">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Do_Corrective" VALUE="Click" onClick="goOpeEvtURL();return     true;" class="button_trevent">
<FORM>
<HTML>
```

Comment: _“Please click test.html to see the result.”_ – clicked your code, nothing happened. Seriously: If you want people to try your code, then provide an only example here – don’t expect everyone that reads your question to do copy&paste just to see what _your_ problem might be.

Comment: CBroe,thank you so much.:) I'll try to modify this question.

Comment: CBroe, I am so sorry. I just make a mistake in test.html .Now i have modied it.

Comment: Off topic: You appear to have missed the `DOCTYPE` from the top of your HTML code. You shoul always include a valid doctype to ensure that the page does not go into quirks mode.

Comment: Thanks，for your advice.

Comment: Is your page really saved in `charset=shift_jis`?

Answer (score 5):

that is ie's bug.
please look at this arcticle.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2909974

Summary

When used with the built-in Administrator Internet Explorer 11, and you open a new window named, such as window.open method, the window name is not recognized. So, the following phenomena occur.
If you specify in window.open method window named, rather than a window that is already open, URL is displayed in a new tab or new window
If you specify in the target attribute of the link or form window named, rather than a window that is already open, URL is displayed in a new tab or new window

Workaround
1. Create a new user account other than the built-in Administrator
2. Enable the policy: [User Account Control:the Use Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account]

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Try to sumarize the content of the link in your answer so if the link goes broken the answer will be valid. Moreover, **the link is broken right now**.

Comment: This kind of answer all not well received in this community and could probably be deleted if you don't improve it. But, besides all of that, have you readed that **the link is not valid**? Doesn't exist.

Comment: I tested it. The link is valid.

Comment: Edit your answer instead of posting that as a comment. You have the "edit" button beneath your answer. And the link is broken for me, maybe is just me =/

Comment: +1 Nice answer now. The URL didn't work for me yet. You can delete the comments that are not necessary, like the ones answering.

Comment: Link doesn't work for me either, but I found a different page: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a5c294e2-e407-491d-ba6a-b7f7edbcabaf/ie11-cant-post-form-data-to-specific-frame-or-window-dialog-opened-via-windowopen?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

You want your OnSubmit method to **return false** if you hope to suppress the default submission behavior and only have one new window open.

Keep in mind that your **target=a.html** attribute opens a new window *named* "a.html", it doesn't open a new window that navigates to "a.html".

Comment: Thank you so much for answer my question. I  am sorry that I hava made a mistake in the test.html . It's not [target=a.html],it is TARGET="aaaaa".

And I found this question only happened in Windows2012R2.In windows8.1 it is OK. 

But the IE11's VL is same in these two OS.